# Ubuntu how to check current CPU temperature in C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, kernel, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. I want to write a c++ program that would give me the current CPU temperature.
Is there a system call to get this data? 
I want to do it periodically, and pretty frequently. What is the best way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: You'd need to look up in your CPU/Motherboard/OS vendor's specs, if it's actually possible and how

Comment: Please show the code you have written so far.

Comment: @QuantumLicht I don't have any code. If I had any I would post a question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this would do what you require:  package lm_sensors and libsensors (to access it from your programs without reading the values from the sys/ files)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lm_sensors

Comment: Can you please tell me what sys files are you talking about. I don't need a whole library if I can read them myself

Comment: Thank you @Russ Schultz, the most straight forward way is to do this cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp. The issue I had is my Ubuntu was running on a VM, and not all VMs support emulating the temperature sensor. So thermal_zone0 was completely missing on my file system. I switched to Parallels 11, and that solved the problem. It's kind of unrelated, but if anyone runs into this issue, I figured it would be good to write it here